# ERROR: No AuthInfo found for name [object Object]

Tags: apex, object, test-setup, vs-code

Ad the title described, I have the following error:

```
ERROR:  No AuthInfo found for name [object Object].
```

What i did was to install a whole new clean visual studio code, with the related salesforce extensions (I do have also SF CLI).

Then when I try to run any test, I get the following error.

For which I found no answer on google, apart from that it is the class salesforce use for login.

The test result file is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was solved after installing the whole OS from scratch and also vscode with the related extensions.

I mean, I did not reinstalled the whole system because of this, but it got solved ;)